# Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554) - Disable

Tags: typescript

For testing and migration proposes I would like to disable this option (TS2554), but I can't seem to find it regarding the name.

```
{
  "extends": "@quasar/app-webpack/tsconfig-preset",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "????": false
  }
}
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're trying to call a function with 0 arguments when it expects 1. As far as I know, **there is no option you can specify in the tsconfig.json file to allow calls like this**.

If you have control over the function signature, you could change the parameter to be optional. Then you could call the function without passing in an argument. Something like this:

```
function myFunction(a?: any){
  console.log(a);
}

myFunction();
```

If you do not have control over the function signature, you could cast the function like this:

```
function myFunction(a: string){
  console.log(a);
}

(myFunction as () => undefined)();
```

You can also use a `@ts-ignore` comment to tell the Typescript compiler to not type check your call to the function:

```
function myFunction(a: string){
  console.log(a);
}

// @ts-ignore
myFunction();
```

Those last 2 options are unsafe, unless you're sure that the function is equipped to handle a call without arguments.

Comment: I know this. But I want to disable it. That's it

Comment: Well, like I said at the start of my answer, there is no `tsconfig.json` option to do what you want. Perhaps you could provide some more background on what the function is you're trying to call without a parameter.